# How do I make the DoTA 2 map work in Source Filmmaker?

Tags: software, animation, production

**Full Question:** How do I use the DoTA 2 map in Source Filmmaker? Every time I load it up, it crashes.

---

I've been trying to use the DoTA 2 map in Source Filmmaker, but every time I try to load it, the program crashes. I have the DoTA 2 assets extracted and mounted, but loading the map seem to be the thing that always cause it to crash.

I can load all the models (ie. Couriers, Heroes, Gear, map props etc.) fine. But loading the DoTA 2 playing-field map doesn't work.

**These are two of the heroes/champions; Viper and Teemo* along with a bunch of other stuff, in the Counter-Strike: Global Offensive map de_nuke.**
Characters and models work. Not the map. Why? and how do I fix it?
[image: These are two of the heroes/champions; Viper and Teemo* along with a bunch of other stuff, in the Counter-Strike: Global Offensive map de_nuke.]

Note:** Not from the game DoTA 2.*

---

Also, going "File > Load Map > [Map name].bsp" (or Ctrl-L) does not work.

Comment: What exactly is the message you get when loading a Dota 2 map?

Comment: Nothing. It just closes and crashes. (Basically, the usual "Not responding" then suddenly closing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hard to say what exactly is the issue without an error message.
Maybe you haven't properly exported the maps and or setup SFM for Dota 2 content. There is a nice guide [here](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=313936526&insideModal=1) that goes through the whole process step by step.

You also want to check the cache and local file for both SFM and Dota 2, if an error gets detected re-export the Dota 2 content afterwards.

Comment: All I ended up is with [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwKSWSGbynZvOUhOZGM2MndoMDg/view?usp=sharing). (It's the crash file uploaded as a .zip)